# Leaflet Create marker from map click and also access end of drag event

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want to have user add (by mouse click) ONE, single marker, on my map. This marker will then be drag-able and report it's lat/lng position to the UI using the markers 'dragend' event.

The code below reports dragend events but if I (uncomment) and add the marker with the onclick event, I can still drag them, but they do not fire the dragend event.

I have tried various arrangements but the dragend event only seems to work if the click event is 'not' set
I have also tried setting the marker variable outside of the callbacks, thinking this was about scope

```
var marker = L.marker([-37,175],{
draggable: true
}).addTo(mymap);

// mymap.on('click', function(e) {        
//     marker = new L.marker([e.latlng.lat,e.latlng.lng],{
//     draggable: true
//   }).addTo(mymap);
//   document.getElementById('lat').value = e.latlng.lat;
//   document.getElementById('lng').value = e.latlng.lng;     
// });

marker.on('dragend', function (e) {
document.getElementById('lat').value = marker.getLatLng().lat;
document.getElementById('lng').value = marker.getLatLng().lng;
  });
```

Comment: It is about scope, but not quite in the way you thought. Your `click` function creates a new `L.marker` which doesn't have a `dragend` function attached. You need to move the `marker.on('dragend')` code to execute within the `click` code after the new marker is added.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION as per @peeebeee

```
mymap.on('click', function(e) {        
 marker = L.marker([e.latlng.lat,e.latlng.lng],{
 draggable: true
 }).addTo(mymap);
 document.getElementById('lat').value = e.latlng.lat;
 document.getElementById('lng').value = e.latlng.lng;  

   marker.on('dragend', function (e) {
   document.getElementById('lat').value = marker.getLatLng().lat;
   document.getElementById('lng').value = marker.getLatLng().lng;
   });   
});
```